# How To Change Footer Power By And Add Store Name

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to opencart,i am trying to change the store name in footer.

please answer me fast.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl

```
<div class="container-fluid bottom-footer">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <p>Copyright 2016. Cartridgewala.com. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <p><img src="<?php echo 'image/weaccept.png'; ?>" title=" " alt=" " class="img-responsive" style=" display:inline-block" /></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```